# Selecting rows from pandas DataFrame using a list

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of lists as below

```
[[1, 2], [1, 3]]
```

The DataFrame is similar to

```
  A B C
0 1 2 4
1 0 1 2
2 1 3 0
```

I would like a DataFrame, if the value in column A is equal to the first element of any of the nested lists and the value in column B of the corresponding row is equal to the second element of that same nested list.

Thus the resulting DataFrame should be

```
  A B C
0 1 2 4
2 1 3 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below do want you need:

```
tmp_filter = pandas.DataFrame(None) #The dataframe you want
# Create your list and your dataframe
tmp_list = [[1, 2], [1, 3]]
tmp_df = pandas.DataFrame([[1,2,4],[0,1,2],[1,3,0]], columns = ['A','B','C'])

#This function will pass the df pass columns by columns and
#only keep the columns with the value you want
def pass_true_df(df, cond):
    for i, c in enumerate(cond):
        df = df[df.iloc[:,i] == c]
    return df

# Pass through your list and add the row you want to keep
for i in tmp_list:
    tmp_filter = pandas.concat([tmp_filter, pass_true_df(tmp_df, i)])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas
df = pandas.DataFrame([[1,2,4],[0,1,2],[1,3,0],[0,2,5],[1,4,0]],
                      columns = ['A','B','C'])
filt = pandas.DataFrame([[1, 2], [1, 3],[0,2]],
                          columns = ['A','B'])

accum = []

#grouped to-filter
data_g = df.groupby('A')
for k2,v2 in data_g:
    accum.append(v2[v2.B.isin(filt.B[filt.A==k2])])

print(pandas.concat(accum))
```

result:

> ```
>    A  B  C
> 3  0  2  5
> 0  1  2  4
> 2  1  3  0
> ```

(I made the data and filter a little more complicated as a test.)